# Javadoc-like documentation in Google Apps Script editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, documentation, editor

Is there any way to access the documentation for functions directly from the Google Apps Script editor?  I'd like to do so either as I'm typing the function name, as well as when looking at existing code.

For example, when examining the following line of code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

I'd like to be able to hover over or right click `getActiveSpreadsheet()`, and be shown the appropriate documentation that describes this function's behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the Apps Script code editor doesn't have this feature, but you can file a [feature request](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#features) to have it added.